# Formatted sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to make a SQL Server sequence formatted like this `VT-000/2015`,
where the zero's is the bill number which increments every record, starting from one in same year which is 2015
e.g:

```
VT-001/2014,
VT-002/2014,
VT-003/2014,
VT-004/2014,
VT-001/2015,
VT-002/2015
```

How can I make this?

Comment: Do you need to generate this upon any insert?

Comment: What happens if there is 1000 bill records for the same year?

Comment: yes , when i insert record with date it generate this id where the year of id is the year of inserted date

Comment: @FutbolFan i dont think it will reach or exceed 1000 record so what i can do is make it is increase number of digits to 4 .

Comment: @FutbolFan yes i know it well be very hard if this happen and i liked your idea but there is  identity problem which is when it reach 15 it's next value should be 16 but it jumps to 1016 i dont know why ?

Comment: @IslamGx Please ignore my comments from earlier. I think your better option would be to create a view rather than a computed column. As I see it, this would make it easier in case your bill records exceed 1000 records for the same year. Also, you don't need to update the base table in order to do so. Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider your table is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT ([SERIAL] NVARCHAR(30), [YEAR] INT, [COUNTER] INT)
```

Here is the procedure you can use:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PRODUCT_INSERT
@YEAR INT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @COUNTER INT
    SELECT @COUNTER = ISNULL(MAX([COUNTER]), 0) + 1 FROM PRODUCT
    WHERE [YEAR] = @YEAR
    INSERT INTO PRODUCT
    VALUES ('VT-' + REPLACE(STR(@COUNTER, 3), SPACE(1), '0') + '/' + CONVERT(nvarchar(4),@YEAR), @YEAR, @COUNTER)
END
```

Comment: when i add 3 records with id's VT-001/2014,VT-002/2014,VT-003/2014 then i delete record number 2 it will case error here !!

Answer (score 0):

Materializing the row number in the table is problematic.  I think a view is the right tool for this job.

Here is one way to do this by creating a view and using `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT (PRODUCT_ID int,YEAR INT);

CREATE VIEW dbo.VIEW_PRODUCT AS
SELECT 
      PRODUCT_ID,
      [YEAR], 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [YEAR] ORDER by [YEAR]) AS RowNum,
      'VT-' + RIGHT(replicate('0', 3) 
       + cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [YEAR] ORDER by [YEAR]) AS VARCHAR(10)), 3) 
       + '/' + cast(YEAR AS VARCHAR(4)) as SERIAL
FROM PRODUCT;

INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES
(1000,2014),
(2000,2014),
(3000,2015),
(4000,2015),
(5000,2015);
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f1b9b/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

If you're on SQL Server 2012, you can use sequences and a computed column - like this:

Step 1: define your sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.YearlyNumbers
   START WITH 1
   INCREMENT BY 1 ;
GO
```

You can reset that sequence back to 1 every January 1 of a new year, to get new numbers starting at 1, for the new year

Step 2: define your table, include a **computed column** that concatenates together the various bits and pieces:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Product 
(
    ProductID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    ProductDate DATE,
    -- default constraint gets a new value from the sequence on every insert
    SequenceValue INT
       CONSTRAINT DF_Product_SeqValue DEFAULT(NEXT VALUE FOR YearlyNumbers),
    -- computed column puts together all bits to create the formatted ID you're looking for   
    FormattedID AS 'VT-' + RIGHT('0000' + CAST(SequenceValue AS VARCHAR(4)), 4) + 
                   '/' + CAST(YEAR(ProductDate) AS VARCHAR(4)) PERSISTED
)
```

Now, when you insert values into your table:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Product (ProductDate)
VALUES ('20150115'), ('20150331'), ('20150222'), ('20150414'), ('20150526')
```

the `INSERT` will fetch values from the sequence, and the computed column shows the formatted ID as requested:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Product
```

[image]